# T4 Template with support for inheritance in tables?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, t4

I'm having a problem with my T4 Template that doesn't offer support for inhertied tables.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Edit:
I created 2 tables. One parent and 2 childs in my entity model.

Eg.

Parent :
Vehicle {weight:int; cost: int; name: string}

Child:
Car {LicensePlate: string; Type:string; Mileage:int;TopSpeed:int; GasTankContents:int;}
Bicycle {hasLights:boolean;Type:string;GenderTypeBike:Char;}

Both Car and Bicycle inherit from Vehicle in my entity model.

But when i generate the relevant classes using a t4 template, it doesn't creates the Car and the Bicycle class.
But the Vehicle class get's created...

:(

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't offer support for inherited tables*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POCO and SelfTracking T4s downloadable from gallery (or extensions manager),
both support inheritance.

Perhaps your conceptual model has a bug in it.
Do you get any errors or warnings in error window,
while saving the edmx file?

Are you working model first or database first?

Are you using a custom template you wrote/modified?